# Хочу сделать счетчик просмотров но не выводиться количество просмотров

Tags: html, python, django

Делаю счетчик просмотров к статье все сделал вродибы окей но количество просмотров всегда стоит 0. Или есть какой нибудь другой способ сделать счетчик просмотров ?

views.py

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    articles = Articles.objects.get(id=pk)

    if not request.user.seen_posts.filter(post_id=pk).exists():
        articles.views += 1
        articles.save()
        Articles.objects.create(user=request.user, post=articles)

    return render(request, 'news/post.html', {'Post': articles})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    article_like = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    article_dislike = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

шаблон

```
 {% for article in object_list  %}

<h3> {{ article.views }} </h3>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[

    path('<int:pk>/article', views.post_views, name='Views'),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**models.py**

```
class PageHit(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(unique=True)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

**decorators.py**

```
from functools import wraps
from django.db.models import F
from django.db import transaction

def counted(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            counter, created = PageHit.objects.get_or_create(url=request.path)
            counter.count = F('count') + 1
            counter.save()
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

**views.py**

```
from .decorators import counted

@counted
def post_detail(request, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'news/post_detail.html', {'post': article})
```

**templatetags/counter.py**

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def page_hits(ctx, page_url=None):
    counter = (PageHit.objects
                      .filter(url=(ctx['request'].path if page_url is None else page_url))
                      .first())
    return 0 if counter is None else counter.count
```

**news/post_list.html**

```
{% load counter %}

{% for article in object_list  %}
    <h3>{% page_hits article.get_absolute_url %}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

**news/post_detail.html**

```
{% load counter %}

<span>{% page_hits %}</span>
```

Или можно написать middleware, который будет делать то же самое для всех запросов.

Comment: Вышла ошибка пишет 'counter' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of: admin_list admin_modify admin_static admin_urls cache i18n l10n log static staticfiles tz

Comment: Нужно внимательно прочитать [этот раздел документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: Все еще не работает я прочел все что ты скинул . Но все еще не заработало. Из менил декораторы но они потом вообще не заработали

Comment: Сделал специально для вас демонстрационный проект - https://github.com/TheDeadOne/django-counter-example

Comment: За последние два года я уже несколько раз давал этот код на разных ресурсах. Вы первый, кто не смог с ним справиться. Если не секрет, по какому учебнику вы изучали Python и как давно начали?

Comment: Был игроделом но решил делать сайты хочу на курсы . В своем городе но пока нечего не понимаю да и репетиро постоянно гуглит вопросы

Comment: Рекомендую не тыкаться в слепую, а прочитать сначала учебник по Python, а потом руководство Django от начала до конца.